# MongoDB mongoose findOneAndUpdate() Await does not wait. A3 runs before A2

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, async-await

A3 log runs before A2. How do I fix this? I want to wait until the update returns and use the result for the next logic. Thanks in Advance.

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

console.log('A1');
   // Inserting into DB
   await db.collection(companyCollection).findOneAndUpdate({"_id": new mongo.ObjectID(companyId)}, {$set: company}, {upsert: false}, await async function (err, result) {
      console.log('A2');
      let resultRes = null;
      if (err) {
         resultRes = { success: false };
      } else {
         resultRes = { success: true };
      }
      return callback(err ? true : false, resultRes);
 });
console.log('A3');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findOneAndUpdate` has two signatures, either return a promise, or call a callback. Your version utilizes the callback version, hence adding the `await` is pointless because no promise is being returned.

Here's a simple re-write that utilizes the promise syntax:

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

async function doSomething() {
    console.log('A1');
    // Inserting into DB
    let result = await db.collection(companyCollection).findOneAndUpdate({"_id": new mongo.ObjectID(companyId)}, {$set: company}, {upsert: false});
    console.log('A2');

    ... do whatever you want ... 
    console.log('A3');
}

return doSomething();
```